# Inline SELECT within CTE inside VIEW that uses a table from the VIEW

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

Hi I want to create a VIEW, with CTE inside, here is my original query (much simplified):

```
SELECT  ISNULL(( SELECT col_a
                 FROM   Table_A a
                 WHERE  a.id = b.id
               ), 'N/A') ,
        b.*
FROM    Table_B b
```

If I want to turn that into a VIEW with CTE, I received the error saying `The multi-part identifier "b.id" could not be bound.`
Here is what I have tried

```
CREATE VIEW my_view
AS
    WITH    my_CTE
              AS ( SELECT   ISNULL(( SELECT col_a
                                     FROM   Table_A a
                                     WHERE  a.id = b.id
                                   ), 'N/A') my_col
                 )
    SELECT  ( SELECT    *
              FROM      my_CTE
            ) CTE_col ,
            b.*
    FROM    Table_B b
```

Notice that the requirement is to have ISNULL go inside the CTE, but that means a.id is an inline query inside CTE, which means I can't do a WHERE clause inside the SELECT of the view.

Answer (score 1):

This is the query:

```
WITH my_CTE AS (
      SELECT ISNULL((SELECT col_a
                     FROM Table_A a
                     WHERE a.id = b.id
                    ), 'N/A'
                   ) my_col
     )
SELECT (SELECT * FROM my_CTE) CTE_col, b.*
FROM Table_B b;
```

The CTE references `b` in the subquery.  It is not defined at that point.  You cannot split off a correlated subquery in a CTE.

You might be able to do what you want with `cross apply`:

```
SELECT my_CTE.my_col CTE_col, b.*
FROM Table_B b CROSS APPLY
     (SELECT ISNULL((SELECT col_a
                     FROM Table_A a
                     WHERE a.id = b.id
                    ), 'N/A'
                   ) my_col
     ) my_CTE
```

There are other ways to simplify your specific query, but this might solve your larger problem.

Comment: Thanks, but I see that your CROSS APPLY is not much different from my original query. The goal was to separate out that ISNULL inline query from the main VIEW because the real one is quite massive.

Answer (score 1):

I would remove the `WHERE` clause inside the CTE and join then the CTE and your `Table_B` together. It should look like this:

```
CREATE VIEW my_view
AS
    WITH    my_CTE
              AS ( SELECT   my_col = ISNULL(col_a, 'N/A') ,
                            a.id
                   FROM     Table_A a
                 )
    SELECT  CTE_col = my_CTE.my_col ,
            b.*
    FROM    Table_B b
            JOIN my_CTE ON b.id = my_CTE.id
```

EDIT:

I have never worked with `FOR XML PATH` so far, so I´m not certain if this is what you want.
Here is a CTE for joining the two tables and a CTE just for the XML.

Maybe the `JOIN` needs to be a `LEFT JOIN` but that depends on your data.
If `Table_A` always has corresponding IDs and `col_a` is just nullable, the `INNER JOIN` is sufficient.
If you want to display `N/A` for a not existing record in `Table_A` you will need a `LEFT JOIN`.

```
CREATE VIEW my_view
AS
    WITH    my_CTE
              AS ( SELECT   my_col = ISNULL(a.col_a, 'N/A') ,
                            b.*
                   FROM     Table_A a
                            INNER JOIN Table_B b ON a.id = b.id
                 ),
            xml_cte
              AS ( SELECT   my_col
                   FROM     my_CTE
                   FOR      XML PATH
                 )
    SELECT  *
    FROM    my_CTE
```

Comment: This was what I original thought but the inline SELECT inside ISNULL contains FOR XML PATH, which is why I can't expose the id outside ISNULL within the CTE.

Comment: I think you should include `FOR XML PATH` in your question and example to clarify why you can´t expose the ID. At the moment it`s a little bit hard to understand what you are trying to achive when someone reads your question.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative:
(The code below is complete. Had posting issues similar to discussion in comments of https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/185681. I actually cannot post the answer without leaving this SO link in the text. ??? I apologize.)

```
WITH my_CTE(b_id, col_A) AS
(
          SELECT b.id, ISNULL(a.col_a, 'N/A')
            FROM Table_B b
 LEFT OUTER JOIN Table_A a ON b.id = a.id
)
        SELECT my_CTE.col_A, b.*
          FROM Table_B b
    INNER JOIN my_CTE ON b.id = my_CTE.b_id
```

Comment: How do you compare yours with NePh's? I think you both went the same direction: expose the id from CTE and join with the main SELECT in the view. But yours have two joins while NePh's has one.

Comment: NePh explanation about the joins explains the subtle difference. Since your example did an `ISNULL` around the join between `a` and `b`, I inferred you might want 'N/A' if there was _also_ no matching `a` record for any `b` record. NePh's first suggestion _only_ returns rows where there is a match between `a` and `b`. That's the main difference. You need to determine which suggestion meets your requirements.